# Best Practices for Optimizing Visual Studio Code Performance on WSL2 with Different Storage

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm experiencing performance issues when using Visual Studio Code on WSL with projects stored on a different drive (`D:`), while my main drive is on "`C:`". Visual Studio Code even displays a warning:
"This workspace is on the Windows file system (/mnt/). For best performance, we recommend moving the workspace to the Linux file system (~/home)."

I would like to know what the best practices are for handling this situation and optimizing VS Code performance.

Some specific questions:

1. How can I improve speed when working with projects located on a different drive in WSL?
2. Are there any specific configurations in WSL or Visual Studio Code that could enhance performance under these conditions?
3. Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found an effective solution that does not involve copying the project to the `/home` directory?

I appreciate any guidance or shared experiences in advance!